# NFS Server changes in /etc/exports file need Service Restart?

Tags: mount, nfs, services

I have NFSv4 Server (on RHELv6.4) and NFS Clients on (CentOSv6.4). Let's say in `/etc/exports`:

```
/shares/website1      <ip-client-1>(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/shares/website2      <ip-client-2>(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

Then whenever i made some changes in that (let's say the changes ONLY for `client-2`), e.g:

```
/shares/website1      <ip-client-1>(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/shares/xxxxxxxx      <ip-client-2>(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

Then i always `service nfs restart`. And then eventually .. the mount-point on `client-1` got **unresponsive** *(Can't open its files, etc)*. *(Why? Because of RESTART?)*

But as described, i only modified the line for `client-2` only. Everything for the `client-1` are still untouched.

So my questions here are:

- Whenever i modify the `/etc/exports`, should i `restart` the service or what?
- If i `service nfs restart`, why the Mount-Point on other Clients are eventually affected? *(For those Client Machines with NO changes made in `/etc/exports` for them.)*

That means, whenever i make the changes in `/etc/exports` and `restart` the service, i will need to go **RE-MOUNT** the directories on **EVERY CLIENTS** in the export list, in order to have the mount-points working again.

Any idea, please?

Comment: After modifying `/etc/exports`, try just running, as root, `exportfs -ra`.  See `man exportfs` for details.

Comment: Then i wouldn't need `nfs restart` anymore?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You shouldn't need to restart NFS every time you make a change to `/etc/exports`. All that's required is to issue the appropriate command after editing the `/etc/exports` file:

```
$ exportfs -ra
```

Excerpt from the official Red Hat documentation titled: [21.7. The /etc/exports Configuration File](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-nfs-server-config-exports.html).

*excerpt*

> When issued manually, the /usr/sbin/exportfs command allows the root user to selectively export or unexport directories without restarting the NFS service. When given the proper options, the /usr/sbin/exportfs command writes the exported file systems to /var/lib/nfs/xtab. Since rpc.mountd refers to the xtab file when deciding access privileges to a file system, changes to the list of exported file systems take effect immediately.

Also read the `exportfs` man page for more details, specifically the "DESCRIPTION" section which explains all this and more.

> DESCRIPTION
>         An  NFS server maintains a table of local physical file systems that are 
>           accessible to NFS clients.  Each file system in this table is  referred 
>           to as an exported file system, or export, for short.
>
> ```
>   The exportfs command maintains the current table of exports for the NFS 
>     server.  The master export table is kept in  a  file  named
>     /var/lib/nfs/etab.  This file is read by rpc.mountd when a client sends 
>     an NFS MOUNT request.
>
>   Normally  the  master  export  table  is  initialized  with the contents 
>     of /etc/exports and files under /etc/exports.d by invoking exportfs -a.  
>     However, a system administrator can choose to add or delete exports 
>     without modifying  /etc/exports  or  files  under /etc/exports.d by 
>     using the exportfs command.
> ```

Also take note of the options we're using, `-ra`:

```
   -a     Export or unexport all directories.
   -r     Reexport all directories, synchronizing /var/lib/nfs/etab with 
          /etc/exports and files  under  /etc/exports.d.   This  option
          removes  entries  in  /var/lib/nfs/etab which have been deleted 
          from /etc/exports or files under /etc/exports.d, and removes
          any entries from the kernel export table which are no longer
          valid.
```

Comment: Is there any advantage with `-ra` instead of  only `-r`?

Comment: @Mvorisek - it's explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I was also wondering if it was necessary to restart, but after some research, I understood that in my case I didn't need to restart, just the export as detailed below.

For reference, the step-by-step procedure I performed:

- needed to get remote access to a folder on another server;
- include "remote_server_ip:/remote_name_folder" in /etc/fstab file;
- after that, to mount and connect to the remote server, I ran the command "sudo mount -a";
- at that moment the error message appeared "mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting remote_server_ip:/remote_name_folder";
- I joined the remote server and configured the ip of the machine that needed access in the /etc/exports file;
- I exported the accesses using the command "**exportfs -av**";
- I went back on the machine that needed access and re-ran the command "sudo mount -a";

So my problem was solved.